# how to take mysql xtrabackup to a remote server

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster, xtrabackup

I have a server running with mysql with huge db of 1 TB.

Now, I want to take full backup through percona xtra backup, because incremental backup is easy with percona xtrabackup.

Now,if I initiate taking backup in that server,storage is getting consumed(I dont want this).
So, I am trying to initate backup in mysql server but the backup need to be stored in a remote server so the existing server storage is not effected.

I have tried the below commands, but even though I have specied remote server ip , it is getting stored in the existing server and storage is getting consumed.

xtrabackup --backup --remote-host=qrnet@10.16.124.208 /home/qrnet/temp

innobackupex --remote-host=qrnet@10.16.124.208 /home/qrnet/temp

so, 10.16.124.208 is the remote server where I need to backup my sql files so that existing server storage does not impact.

But , it is getting stored in the existing server if I perform above commands where the sql is existing.

How to store the backups remotely without effecting existing storage and are there any alternative ways?

Comment: Quickly looking I don't see any options in `xtrabackup` to use remote storage. So, you would need to use NFS or SSHFS mount on the server, which you can use to access the remote storage.

Answer (score 0):

You could also mount a remote (but on LAN) samba share.
This is something that I have used with good results.